# How do I add a placeholder on a FileField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I tried creating placeholder by using the following code:

```
class ReceiptsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Receipts
        fields = ('receipt',)

    widgets = {

            'receipt' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Maximum 3 files allowed.'}),

        }
```

And then rendering by using the following snippet in the template:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form | crispy }}

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mt-1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But still the placeholder text is not appearing besides the fileinput.

Comment: There is no placeholder for input type file. what is the result you expect to get ? You want to change the button text ?

Comment: No, I wanted to give additional helpful information just below the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want, is a help_text. Django defines this in regular Form.

```py
class ReceiptsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Receipts
        fields = ('receipt',)
        help_texts = {
             'receipt': 'YOUR HELP TEXT HERE',
        }
        widgets = {
            'receipt' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }
```

Not sure you need to add form-control CSS class if you are using crispy with BOOSTRAP_PACK ?